# preg_replace on all HTML content in Wordpress

Tags: php

I would like to be able to remove stuff from the HTML of the page eg. replacing all comments in the body tag or remove som unnecessary code.

Is there a way to create a filter like that getting all the content of the page? not only the post content, all content with footer, main, sidebar, header and so on.

Comment: Clear your question. Give specific items name or example which you want removed and show what you've tried till now.

Answer (score 1):

> WordPress doesn't have a "final output" filter.

Just google search I found a  interesting answer from Stack Overflow.

All credits go to [@kfriend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22818089/7117576)

More Details (SO question link) : [Wordpress filter to modify final html output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772510/wordpress-filter-to-modify-final-html-output)

```
<?php

/**
 * Output Buffering
 *
 * Buffers the entire WP process, capturing the final output for manipulation.
 */

ob_start();

add_action('shutdown', function() {
    $final = '';

    // We'll need to get the number of ob levels we're in, so that we can iterate over each, collecting
    // that buffer's output into the final output.
    $levels = ob_get_level();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++)
    {
        $final .= ob_get_clean();
    }

    // Apply any filters to the final output
    echo apply_filters('final_output', $final);
}, 0);
```

An example of hooking into the final_output filter:

```
<?php
add_filter('final_output', function($output) {
    return str_replace('foo', 'bar', $output);
});
?>
```

Comment: This works beautifully as a plugin :)